# How to return items of for loop into a single list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, range

I do not know how I can get all the items from a for loop with a range in a list instead of getting them all separate. 
Lets say I have this code

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5]
new = []
for item in list1[0:-1]:
    new = item+1
    print(new)
```

so if I run this I would get

```
2
3
4
5
```

but I need to get this:

```
[2,3,4,5]
```

the whole point of this problem is to add 1 to every number of the original list except the last one and then replace the third number with a 0.  But if the numbers I get back are not in a list I do not know how to call the third item which I would get like this:

```
new[2]=0
```

Comment: `new.append(item+1)`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `list.append()`:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = []
for item in list1[0:-1]:
    list2.append(item + 1)
```

Alternatively, you could use a list comprehension:

```
list2 = [item + 1 for item in list1[0:-1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner to replace every item `x` in a list with `x + 1`, except the third one, which will be replaced by 0. Also, I'll pass `list1[:-1]` to the list comprehension to omit the last element, as OP already did:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
new = [x + 1 if i != 2 else 0 for i,x in enumerate(list1[:-1])]
# new == [2, 3, 0, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5]
print [x+1 if i != 2 else 0 for i, x in enumerate(list1)]
#[2,3,0,5,6]
```